# Flutter Firebase Security Rules does not work

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to change the security rules from

```
match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write;       
}
```

to allow only the authenticated users.

I changed this rule to:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

It works in the "rules playground" but when I run the app, it gives the error below:

```
[WriteStream]: (c1114d) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED,     description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documentReferenceSet     
(package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1009:7)

<asynchronous suspension>

MethodChannelDocumentReference.set       
  (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.   dart:35:7)
 <asynchronous suspension>
```

Actions:

My DB has collections inside collections in some of my collections, so, I changed the rule to :

this format in case of the collection "count" that only has documents:

```
match  /count/{document=**} {  
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid !=null;       
}
```

and to this format if the collections (comments) has documents that have sub collections that have documents

```
match  /comments/{comments} {  
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid !=null;
  
    match  /comments/{comments} {  
         allow read;
         allow write: if request.auth.uid !=null;
    }                                               
  }
```

If the above `if request.auth.uid !=null;`  is replaced by `true;` everything works perfectly, but it is not secured since even unauthenticated users can write into the DB.

I am using Android Studio and Flutter.

Comment: The users can join the app via firebase auth and/or the google sign in.

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated when you perform the request? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual **code** that triggers this error message. In that code, make sure to prove that it meets the requirements of your rules, i.e. check that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null` right before you call the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo  Yes, I am sure that the user has loged in using either the email/password or the google sign in.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. The code is: 
Documentsnapshot doc = await countRef.doc(userId).get();  
setState((){
if (!doc.exists){
Score =0;
}
if (doc.exists){
Score=doc['Score'];
}
});

Comment: Don't show the code in a comment, but edit your question to include. Also: don't tell us that you're certain the user is signed in, but write code that proves it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to confirm that the user has logged in via Firebase authentication and if you want to secure all Firestore documents you can use this rule to give only authorized user access to data

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sure that the user loged in.